# How to search the app store with curl

Tags: php, ios, curl, app-store

I have been requested by a friend to search the IOS app store for apps that fall between a certain number of downloads.

I would like to do this using curl, and have a response given in the form of json or some other parseable format.

Ideally I would would be doing this with PHP.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no API that allows you to get that information from the iOS AppStore.

In this page:

http://www.iosappstats.com/

You can find some general statistics, but I dont think they have a public API that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to any download stats on iOs that aren't for an app you manage. This is impossible